# Help me to understand what element_child() does

Tags: 6, forms

Can anybody help me understand what **element_child** is doing?

It is called as `element_children($form)` where form contains keys like "cancel", "submit" and "#redirect".

This snippet from common.inc

```
/**
 * Check if the key is a child.
 */
function element_child($key) {
  return !isset($key[0]) || $key[0] != '#';
}

/**
 * Get keys of a structured array tree element that are not properties (i.e., do not begin with '#').
 */
function element_children($element) {
  return array_filter(array_keys((array) $element), 'element_child');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have an array as the following (it's an array as accepted from the form API):

```
  $form['example_text'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#title' => t('Testing text'), 
    '#default_value' => '', 
    '#size' => 45, 
    '#maxlength' => 45, 
    '#required' => TRUE, 
    '#description' => t('This is an example form demonstrating forms usage in the installer profiles tasks. Enter any text to see what happens.'),
  );

  $form['continue'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit', 
    '#value' => t('Continue'),
  );

  $form['errors'] = array();
  $form['#action'] = $url;
  $form['#redirect'] = FALSE;
```

If you execute `element_children($form)` will return an array containing the following indexes:

- example_text
- continue
- errors

When `$key` is a string `$key[0]` is the first character of that string. The value of `!isset($key[0]) || $key[0] != '#'` is `TRUE` when the string `$key` is empty, or when the first character of that string is not *#*; `array_filter()` returns an array containing the keys and values for which the function referred as second argument returns `TRUE`.

The reason to do this is that, in the array used by the form API, keys starting with *#* are considered properties of that form field (or of the form), while keys that don't start with *#* are considered child of that form field; in the example code I used, '#redirect' is a property of the form, while 'example_text' is a form field that is child of the form.

Comment: Many thanks! But isn't $key[0] deprecated syntax in php? It should be using $key{0} instead?

Comment: The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) doesn't report that `$key[0]` is deprecated. As far as I remember, the last introduced syntax is `$key[0]`, while `$key{0}` was introduced first. I prefer using `$key[0]`, as it reminds me of the array access.

Comment: Is it? I just now read the book: PHP5 and Mysql Bible and the author mentions that [i] syntax is deprecated (PHP4) and {i} is the recommended one. This fact confused me as Drupal code is scrutinized by expert people ..

Comment: What is the point of checking with !isset($key[0]) for checking the first character? I can imagine no case where first character of a string is not set. So this will check only an empty or non-existant string. If it is non-existant why does it need to return true?

Comment: If the string is empty, `$key[0]` is undefined, and the next expression would cause the "access to a not defined variable" error; `!isset($key[0])` avoids the other expression is evaluated, and it is necessary, as an empty string is not used for properties.